# glortho zox plane projection

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, projection

I need to make an opengl projection on a plane paralel with XOZ plane (perpendicular on OY).

Can you explain me what parameters I should use with glOrtho to make this projection.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording of your question is not entirely clear to me, but if you want to display things in a "2D" fashion, this is how to do it:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, window_x_size, window_y_size, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: I have a 3d cube and I want to make a projection of the face paralel to XOZ plane